# Scrolling inside an iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll, scrollto

Here's the deal:
I spent 5 hours looking for a good solution for my problem and found many (unfortunately not working, or it was me doing sth wrong).

I have a page, in which I have an iFrame.
I do not want to scroll the page to see the iFrame properly.
My point is to scroll the iFrame in that page so it would change it's position (page inside iFrame).

What won't work: putting a window scrollTo into a iFrame page code (simply because this page is not mine, so i.e.: I have my own page and in iFrame I have stackoverflow.com, and I want it to scroll 100px to the right and 500px to the bottom).

I hope you got my point, and will help me to fix it.

Just please, be kind and give me the whole working example with an iFrame. I just can't stand spending any more time on figuring it out... Is it even possible? ...

Comment: So you want to scroll an iframe that doesn't belong to you? That might be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is as follows:

```
 <div id="fakeiframe" style="height: 500px; width: 800px; 
             overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;">
 <iframe src="http://www.washingtonpost.com/" 
         style="width: 1500px; height: 2000px;"></iframe>
 </div>
```

The `div` size should be smaller than the `iframe` size. Then, you can scroll the "iframe" using `document.getElementById('fakeiframe').scrollTo(x,y);`

You can modify the CSS to tweak the frame to your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is what he needs: `My point is to scroll the iFrame in that page so it would change it's position (page inside iFrame).`

Comment: Pekka got it. Sorry, benastan, but you did not help me.

Scroll iframe that doesn't belong to me is impossible? It's just like I want to scroll a page in a page ... why do you think this is impossible?

Comment: Using the div as window for the iframe, very cleaver way!

Answer (score 1):

Pekka is correct - it's not possible. Because the iframe's `src` is from a different domain, no browser will let code from the parent window access the DOM or window. This is important and intentional. If pages are from different domains, it's entirely possible that a malicious script running in a separate window could cause serious problems in the parent window.